# Sending data issue TCP/IP

Tags: c++, tcp

```
//------------------------------
    //creating dynamic array to send
    std::list<char> list;
    char in=NULL;
    while(1)
    {
        scanf("%c",&in);
        if(in=='\n') break;
        list.push_back(in);
    }
    //char *sendbuf=NULL;
    char* sendbuf=new char[list.size()]; // create a dynamic array   

        std::copy(list.begin(),list.end(),sendbuf); // copy the data 
        //sendbuf=array;
        iResult_send = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
        delete [] sendbuf; // destroy the dynamic array
        list.clear();
}
//-------------------------------------------
```

Hi all,
I'm trying to send data to client through the dinamic array that i'm creating.
when i sent data with static array char type the client got it just fine. but when i'm sending like that he is getting a lot of garbage after the message.
Is there anything wrong with my array that i'm sneding?

Comment: *Aside*: Your entire code fragment can be reduced to: `{ std::string s; std::getline(std::cin, s); send( ConnectSocket, s.data(), (int)s.size(), 0 ); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iResult_send = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf,` **(int)strlen(sendbuf)**`, 0 );`

Message size determination is wrong. Try to use list.size() against it.

Comment: Another big problem is that unless the client is psychic, it has no way of knowing what the message size is, since the size isn't communicated and the data is not null-terminated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: your data is not null terminated, thus strlen() does not yield the correct size. (Presumably a way to big value).

correct is:

```
    iResult_send = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, sizeof(char) * list.size(), 0 );
```

btw: you can omitt the

```
        list.clear(); 
    }
```

the variable is destructed at the end of the block.